# How to express that a decision has developed from a thought?

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

Good evening from Germany!

I'm currently writing a personal statement for my UCAS application and have got a problem concerning one of my sentences. Originally, I wrote:

*The decision to study X **emerged** during the last year and was...*

What I would like to express is that this is not something that I've always wanted to do, but that I first thought about studying X about a year ago and that it developed into the decision to apply for this course.

Not, I revised my personal statement with a former tutor of mine, who said that the verb “emerge“ (obviously) is not correct in this context. It's just that the German translation emphasized exactly what I wanted to express with this sentence. My tutor told me, it was better to write it like that:

*The decision to study X **came** during the last year and was...*

Personally, I'm not sure that is exactly what I want either. Sure, it expresses very clearly what I try to convey with this sentence, but still, it just doesn't seem elegant or formal enough for a personal statement that tutors of some of the best universities in the U.K. will read. Especially since this is the opening sentence.

Unsure if my tutors approach was the best, I contacted an online service that offers to revise your personal statement and improve it. Their approach, given my original version, was this:

***My*** decision to study X **is one I have contemplated during the last year and...**

So, they changed it to *my* decision and obviously used a pretty different expression which I am not sure of if it conveys exactly what I want to say.

Now you may say, that's only one sentence in a 4000 character long personal statement! Sure, but it's the opening sentence and, as I said, tutors of some of the best universities in the U.K. are going to read it, so I want to make a strong first impression.

What do you say, how would you write my opening sentence? And what do you think: *my* decision or *the* decision? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I disagree that *emerged* is inappropriate. It makes sense to me. It's the same thing as saying that your decision *firmed up* or *solidified*. It's something that you became aware of. Alternatively, if it's the collocation of *decision* with emerged that you don't like, you could say that your *desire* to study X emerged . . .

Comment: Developed? Formulated? Check them in a dictionary to see if they mean what you want

Comment: @JasonBassford. Thank you, that is REALLY good. Exactly what I was looking for! My desire emerged... genius! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm converting a comment I made to the question into an answer because of how well received it was—and it might be beneficial to someone else in the future.

---

Mirroring another answer, I disagree that **emerged** is inappropriate.

It's the same thing as saying that your decision firmed up or solidified, and that it's something that you became aware of over the last year.

I think that it better captures the sense of your realization of what you wanted to study than dropping it would.

---

However, if it is the collocation of *decision* with **emerged** that you don't like, you could use a different noun:

> My **desire** to study X emerged during the last year . . .

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence:

> The decision to study X emerged during the last year and was...

Adding 'my' clearly idicates it was your decision:

> My decision to study X only emerged during the last year and was...

And the use of [emerge](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/emerge) is apropos.

> to become apparent

My sense is this is formal enough but if you want to the 'contemplate' sentence, it would work too!

Answer (score 0):

You could say "I came to the decision to study X after much deliberation". This has the advantage of being in the active voice and making it clearer that the decision was positive and well-considered. Alternatives are "I decided to" instead of "I came to the decision to" and "consideration" rather than "deliberation" but the meaning would be similar. I only suggest the longer version because it has slight implications of longer and more careful thought.